# C++ methods in derived classes with different parameters

Tags: c++, overloading

This is a question about how to implement some needs I have been having lately. I am sure there is a pattern or common solution for this and, even though I've come with one, I am eager to learn more.

Suppose I am working in a game in which all entities related to the game itself are derived from a class "Actor" (say "obstacle", "moving obstacle", "projectile" and "cannon"). In game, all those entities are stored in a `std::vector<Actor *>` vector so they can be traversed.

Now, let's suppose each "Actor" can "do" something at each turn and let's give them a method "act". Obstacle::act would do little, Moving_obstacle::act and Projectile::act would move them around and "Cannon::act" would create a new projectile. It sort of makes sense to have a pure virtual function Actor::act so I can in turn do something like:

```
std::vector<Actor *>::iterator b=myvectorofactors.begin(), e=myvectorofactors.end();
while(b < e)
{
    *b->act();
     b++;
}
```

And have them all "acting". Well, so far so good... The thing is, Cannon::act could have a different prototype or return value (for example, to store a generated projectile and leter have it pushed into the vector) and this one "small" difference breaks it all.

Now, I know that from certain standpoint these method overloads are completely different functions each. I also know that one can always plan in advance and engineer through the problem with enough foresight... Or one can just manuever around the problem.

In this case at hand, I just used different unique identificators for each derived Actor class and used them to cast to the correspondent class and do the work around them. I am sure I will come around the same problem again and I am curious to know about some entry level solutions.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: less wall of text, more example code, please

Comment: Can't agree @Dave, it's a well thought out question.

Comment: You might want to look at the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: Well, in my opinion, if you start having this problem, maybe the designed is flawed from the start ? Ask yourself what is the meaning of the function `act()`. If the answer is overly broad (which is equivalent to finding out that `act()` has no real meaning unless you implement it...), then you should consider revising your design (I'd undoubtedly do it myself).

Comment: This smells like a case of Bad Inheritance. If `Cannon::act()` needs a different signature, then is it really an `Actor`? See the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot to all. Agree with the bad inheritance syndrom: it actually stinks the code all around. Revisiting the design... well, a bit late at this stage (specially for something I do for fun and learning, the game is almost finished!) but real food for thought the next time around. Finally, thanks Nick, will take a second look at the pattern. I read about some php implementation, never for C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The start is sound, you derail here:

> The thing is, Cannon::act could have a different prototype or return value (for example, to store a generated projectile and leter have it pushed into the vector)

Why would it? Act is act. The instance must figure it out without anything else. You shall train it in the ctor, or other calls before acting. Or it shall look around in during the Act call.

Consider: even if you magically had the payload for different params ready, in the quoted while how would it be figured out? The call is abstract. Even if you infested it by some dynamic_cast, still leave the problem which cannon shall get which params?

No, the subjects must cooperate with each other, or use some messaging system (see dispatcher)...

Comment: A messaging system is just what I used in another project. Ended up being overly convoluted - probably bad implementation - so I went and tried something different... I notice the deraling (a lot, each time I look at the code) but never thought about training it in some other method. Will give it some thought in future projects. Thanks.

Comment: Marked as answer. Not that any comment has been unhelpful but the "Act is act" bit really got me. Just FYI I dismantled the whole faulty inheritance and wrote different methods in the game controller and Actor subclasses to work with each particular case (being shoot, move other actors around or anything else). Discerning between classes using the whats_my_type_id method is ugly, but so far enough for this project.

Answer (score 1):

the internal variables that the body of each act is different, and they can use internal private owned/ or inherited variable, so if you can set these variables before calling act, so you don't need to send anything through the parameter to be safe, or to not get in complications

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Thing is, imagine I want to add a new "projectile": Well, I should either return it from somewhere or pass a reference / pointer for me to write in... I assume I can do it problem-free but then again, I would end up static_casting the "Actor" class so I can call these preparation methods. Any ideas about that?

Comment: you can have all act from the base class with a pointer parameter, that is only used by interested instances, and send a null, to those dont need to send anything back,

Comment: That's what I actually had in my "Cannon" class. It would write on the pointer when succesfully firing and then the main controller would check if something was in that pointer so it could be inserted into the Actor vector... Still, I needed many more types of parameters. Thankfully I already solved it: see comments above.

Comment: thats good, however, I have a generic pointer of type void*, and the parameter is casted, depending on what you are sending, you may send anything through a pointer of structure as void*

Comment: Personally I try to shy away from void * (except when a few cases in which I couldn't avoid it, namely SDL library threads) when working with C++. I think it's considered a bad practice, right?. Even though I think there are no absolutes here, why would the void * be there if it was evil?.